# Can a user propose a new badge?

Tags: feature-request, badges

I recently answered a bountied question and my answer was accepted. I got the 50 rep points for the bounty but was surprised there was no badge/medal for collecting my first bounty. Considering you get badges for casting your first vote, answering an old question, and even just visiting the site every day for a month, I found it very surprising there was no badge for successfully collecting my first bounty. Since I assume that badges exist to encourage users to engage in a variety of desired behaviors, it seems there should be one for collecting a first bounty. Is there a way to propose that a “bounty hunter” badge be created?

Answer (score 6):

Badges are shared through the entire StackExchange system.  The best place to ask this is on the StackExchange Meta.

Bounty related badges have [already been suggested](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1182/bounty-hunter-badges), in 2009, so I wouldn't suggest holding your breath.  They don't seem to be high on the priority list.

Comment: Thanks. It isn't a huge deal to me, I just thought it was odd to have a badge for casting your first vote but not something that takes effort and engages what by definition is a tough question. If it's been suggested, I guess I'll leave it at that.